# $P_2$-groups are not always $P_3$-groups : a group by Blackburn

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, p-groups

I am trying to find the group refered to after Collary 8 in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869376900302)  <sup>1</sup>. The relevant quote is:

> A group constructed by Blackburn [3; III.10.15], for which $|G| = p^{p+1}$, $ |\Omega_1 (G)| = p^{p-1}$ and $|\mho_1(G)| = p$ shows that $P_2$-groups are not always $P_3$-groups.
>
> 3. B. HUPPERT, “Endliche Gruppen I,” Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1967.

I do not have access to the the text cited (translated as "Finite Groups"). Does anyone know the group Mann is refering to?

---

For context $\mho_n(G) := \langle g^{p^n} \mid g \in G \rangle$ and
$\Omega_n(G) := \langle g \mid g^{p^n} = 1 \rangle$.

$G$ is called a $P_2$-group if $ \Omega_n(S) = \{ g \mid g^{p^n} = 1 \}$ for all $n$ and every section $S$ of $G$.

And $G$ is called a $P_3$-group if $| \mho_n(S) | =[S:\Omega_n(S)] $ for all $n$ and every section $S$ of $G$,

---

**Reference:**

(1) Mann, A. (1976). The power structure of p-groups. I. Journal of Algebra, 42(1), p.125.

Answer (score 1):

My German is rusty, but I am instead attaching the two relevant pages of the book of Huppert. It's a monstrous book. It appears from a cursory glance that all the notation is pretty ordinary, so I hope it is understandable.

[image]

[image]

It's in German, which I unfortunately can't help you with.

Comment: Well this will be fun ... Thank you!

Comment: Although I don't understand the above construction it seems to be the same group as Exercise 2.4 from 'An Introduction to Finite $p$-Groups' by Gustavo A. Fernández-Alcober's notes. (part 1: https://imgur.com/a/jhiqX and part 2: https://m.imgur.com/a/VCyPo ) When I have more time I may write it up as an answer.